# How can I convert char to string?

Tags: rust, rust-obsolete

> This question pertains to a pre-release version of Rust.
> [This younger question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28003483) is similar.

---

I tried to print one symbol with `println`:

```
fn main() {
    println!('c');
}
```

But I got next error:

```
$ rustc pdst.rs
pdst.rs:2:16: 2:19 error: mismatched types: expected `&str` but found `char` (expected &str but found char)
pdst.rs:2     println!('c');
                          ^~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

How do I convert char to string?

Direct typecast does not work:

```
let text:str = 'c';
let text:&str = 'c';
```

It returns:

```
pdst.rs:7:13: 7:16 error: bare `str` is not a type
pdst.rs:7     let text:str = 'c';
                       ^~~
pdst.rs:7:19: 7:22 error: mismatched types: expected `~str` but found `char` (expected ~str but found char)
pdst.rs:7     let text:str = 'c';
                             ^~~
pdst.rs:8:20: 8:23 error: mismatched types: expected `&str` but found `char` (expected &str but found char)
pdst.rs:8     let text:&str = 'c';
                                  ^~~
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use `char::to_string`, which is [from the `ToString` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#impl-ToString):

```
fn main() {
    let string = 'c'.to_string();
    // or
    println!("{}", 'c');
}
```

Comment: Yes, weirdly the docs refer to to_string() but never actually define it.

Comment: It's from the `ToString` trait, which is automatically implemented on anything that implements the `Display` trait, which includes `char`. (`impl<T> ToString for T where T: Display + ?Sized`) This indirection, however, means that this won't show up in documentation, and is just something you have to memorize/learn.

Answer (score 25):

Using `.to_string()` will allocate `String` on heap. Usually it's not any issue, but if you wish to avoid this and want to get `&str` slice directly, you may alternatively use

```
let mut tmp = [0u8; 4];
let your_string = c.encode_utf8(&mut tmp);
```

Comment: To complete this answer and actually get the `&str` out, you need `std::str::from_utf8(&tmp).unwrap()`.

Comment: @BallpointBen not really - `encode_utf8` returns `&mut str` already.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, you're right

Answer (score 21):

You can now use `c.to_string()`, where `c` is your variable of type `char`.

Comment: This doesn't seem documented explicitly, but it's true because char's implement Display and Display implementations require to_string, but you wouldn't know that from the Display documentation, this is documented on the ToString trait. Which is not very good. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html