# How do I convert a char to a String?

Tags: string, char, rust

Is there a succinct way to convert a `char` to a `String` in Rust other than:

```
let mut s = String::new();
s.push('c');
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You use the `to_string()` method:

```
'c'.to_string()
```

Comment: Hm, that's funny. I searched Rust API for `to_string` but found no implementers that method on char. Could you post a link to it's API. For completeness sake `^_^`!

Comment: @DanielFath: you're looking for [`std::string::ToString::to_string`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html#tymethod.to_string), which has a blanket impl for `T: String`, which `char` implements.

Comment: Oh, so that's how it works. I thought `String` was buffer like structure, while in fact it's a trait. Hmm...

Comment: It's both: http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/string/struct.String.html and http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/fmt/trait.String.html

Answer (score 2):

Since Rust 1.46, `String` implements [`From<char>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-From%3Cchar%3E), so you can alternatively use:

```rust
String::from('c')
```

or, with type inference,

```
'c'.into()
```