# How to convert char* to std::string

Tags: c++, casting, stdstring

The following function returns a char*:

```
 // Returns the pointer to the actual packet data.
 // @param pkt_handle The buffer handle.
 // @param queue      The queue from which the packet is arrived or destined.
 // @return           The pointer on success, NULL otherwise.
u_char * pfring_zc_pkt_buff_data(
  pfring_zc_pkt_buff *pkt_handle,
  pfring_zc_queue *queue
);
```

and the following function takes a string as input.

```
  template<class ...Args>
  bool write(Args&&... recordArgs) {
    auto const currentWrite = writeIndex_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    auto nextRecord = currentWrite + 1;
    if (nextRecord == size_) {
      nextRecord = 0;
    }
    if (nextRecord != readIndex_.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
      new (&records_[currentWrite]) T(std::forward<Args>(recordArgs)...);
      writeIndex_.store(nextRecord, std::memory_order_release);
      return true;
    }

    // queue is full
    return false;
  }
```

I can't change functions code. The `u_char * pfring_zc_pkt_buff_data` returns a pointer to the actual packet captured by `pfring_zc_recv_pkt(zq, &buffers[lru], 1)`.

I need to save part of packet to a buffer, So i have to convert u_char* to string*
.there are many similar questions like:

[How to Convert unsigned char* to std::string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673445/how-to-convert-unsigned-char-to-stdstring-in-c)

[How to convert a const char * to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126498/how-to-convert-a-const-char-to-stdstring)

[How to convert char to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267578/how-to-convert-char-to-string)

I couldn't find proper answer for my question.

here are some of my code.

```
void run() {
    int i=0,n;
    char buf[_snapLengthConnection + _ConnectionHeaderSize];    
    for(;;){
        if(likely(pfring_zc_recv_pkt(zq, &buffers[lru], wait_for_packet)>= 0)) {               
            u_char *pkt_data = pfring_zc_pkt_buff_data(buffers[lru], zq);        
            pfring_print_pkt(buf, sizeof(buf), pkt_data, buffers[lru]->len,sizeof(buf));       

            std::string *payload;

            //need to save buf to payload
            // how do i copy buf to payload?               
            std::cout<< payload<<"=="<<std::endl;               

            _activeBuffer->queue->write(payload);    
        } 
     }

}
```

How do i convert u_char* to string?

OS: Ubuntu

gcc version: 4.8.2

Comment: What do you mean by `std::string *` ?

Comment: @Shravan40. the question is edited

Comment: @m.r226 Do you know the length of the data?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz. the buf holds packet contents. char buf[_snapLengthConnection + _ConnectionHeaderSize];

Comment: In last code, `payload` is an unitialized pointer, you can not use it! both line after declaration of `payload` have undefined behavior

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::string` has a constructor for this:

```
const char *str = "Shravan Kumar";
std::string str(str);
```

Just make sure that your `char *` isn't `NULL`, otherwise it will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: char* is not NULL, I can print its content. Tested this before.

Comment: This only works for C-style strings, which his packet data is not. How would the constructor of `str` know the length of the packet data?